# flash doesn't display on fullscreen in firefox

Tags: firefox, flash-player, fullscreen

When I play videos with the flash player on firefox and switch to fullscreen, I get a white screen. The audio can still be heard. Hitting ESC switches back to normal view.

Please note:

- I have tried disabling all of my addons, didn't help.
- I tried uninstalling flash and reinstalling, didn't help.
- Flash player fullscreen mode works OK on IE, but not on Firefox.
- Firefox version 3.6.10
- I am running the later version of flash player (10.1.85)
- Firefox non-flash fullscreen mode (F11) works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

right-click the flash player, select "settings", and uncheck "hardware acceleration".

See [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=428d6ac12c5e65d0&hl=en)